# pullback of euclidean volume form under map $x\mapsto x/\|x\|^2$, for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, pullback

So let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ be given by $x\mapsto x/\|x\|^2$ where $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm. Let $\omega$ be the euclidean volume form. So, we have that in local coordinates the euclidean volume form is $\omega = dx_1\wedge dx_2\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n$. Then my understanding is that the pullback under $F$ would be simply $\det(JF)\,dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n$ (where $JF$ is the Jacobian of $F$). However, I can't seem to find a nice way of expressing this determinant, which makes me wonder if I am correct. I calculate
$$
   JF=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
   \|x\|^2-2x_1^2  &  -2x_1x_2  & \cdots  &-2x_1x_n\\
   -2x_2x_1  &  ||x||^2-2x_2^2  & \cdots  & -2x_2x_n\\
   \vdots          &   \vdots   & \ddots  & \vdots\\
   -2x_nx_1        &   -2 x_nx_2& \cdots  & \|x\|^2-2x_n^2
   \end{array}\right]\frac{1}{\|x\|^4}
$$
where in local coordinates $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Use the spherical symmetry! At a point $(x_1,0,\ldots,0)$ the determinant is very easy to calculate.

Comment: Why thank you. By rotating into $x$ to $(\|x\|,0,...,0)$ we simplify things greatly.